# Is there a P2P/decentralized "e-mail alternative" which more than 10 people in the world use?

Tags: open-source, api, networking, security, communication

I'm trying to provide a way for myself to reach people who contact me through what is essentially a website form.

The problem with e-mail, the obvious contender, is that it's inherently insecure and privacyless -- both for the sender and the receiver (especially if they are to reply). Even if there may exist some kind of service out there which allows you to pay with Bitcoin and doesn't require an e-mail address to register an account and which promises to not track you, the problem is beyond their powers anyway since the e-mail messages still have to reach the inboxes, which they won't unless you jump through 48 different burning hoops, backwards.

So, long story short: e-mail is out of the question.

But then there's nothing left except these obscure projects such as Bitmessage which nobody has heard of, and which are impossible to make people use (trust me: I've tried!)...

Obviously, Twitter/Facebook/etc. are automatically disqualified since they are not P2P/decentralized whatsoever, and even less private than e-mail.

I wish there were some kind of system which doesn't even require special software to be installed, which uses some sort of existing technology to send JSON blobs around or something. Which is reliable, accountless, decentralized and encrypted.

Or at least depends on some really trustworthy software which is minimal and user-friendly and polished and nice. Not something which pulls down 525 random dependencies and takes a computer hacker to get started with.

You'd think they would have come up with *something* like that by now!

PS: There would be no requirement for this system to be able to send attachments of any kind. Small text messages are quite sufficient.

Comment: Are Messengers out of the question, too? Thinking e.g. of Threema – which is well established and also provides a web front-end. Though with Threema, you'd need to aquire a license first, no mail or phone numbers are registered. There might be comparable services which don't need even the license – like Matrix/Riot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [dmails](https://www.dmail.online/), based on [blockstack](https://blockstack.org/) blockchain:

> Send Emails, Store files and Pay, with the World's FIRST server-less
>   Email service. No more spam. Based on Blockchain Tech.

You may want to watch a [2-minutes video](https://youtu.be/cjFD8u6uNT8) about it.

It's pretty much an e-mail-like app, but it doesn't work with regular e-mails. You exchange messages through blockstack ids (which sound like example.id.blockstack).

But it's in beta and sometimes I get "Something went wrong" error message trying to send.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it meets all your requirements, but you could take a look at [Matrix](https://matrix.org/).  It is an open messaging protocol based on a federated model similar to email, in which messages are replicated across multiple servers.  There are public servers or you can run your own.  End-to-end encryption is possible.  It does require an account, but you don't have to provide an email to create one.  (And if you run your own server you can use whatever kind of account creation process you want.)

There are multiple clients but only one (Riot) consistently keeps up with new additions to the protocol.  The system is still evolving and there can be some wrinkles.  (For instance, using E2EE can be somewhat awkward as every device must verify every other device in an encrypted room, although solutions to this are in the works.)